# Styling last item in ul

Tags: css, list

I'm looking to format the bullets for the last item of the list.

I'm using Firebug to pinpoint where the menu item is and I have two options in front of me:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCJp7.png)

[Screenshot 2 - Includes bullet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j5UC.png)

Now I'm looking at either using CSS or jQuery to select the last item.

I tried using this CSS and it applies to the last TWO items.

```
ul.children li:last-child{ 
color: red; 
list-style-type: circle;
}
```

[Screenshot 3 - Output](http://screencast.com/t/iLQAxcmzAia)

I'm thinking maybe I need to use jQuery but I haven't had luck with that either.

---

Here is my custom walker that displays $output:

```
$output .= $indent . 
'<li><div class="link"><a href="' . get_page_link($page->ID) . '" title="' . 
esc_attr( wp_strip_all_tags( apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, 
$page->ID ) ) ) . '">' . 
$link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . 
$link_after . '</a>' . $MetaOutput . '</div>';
```

I'm going to make a conditional that asks if $MetaOutput's children = 0 , apply this style.

I am going to try and make a class for the

at the beginning. Ideally, I'd like to replace the list-style-image for each li class. I'll edit this again and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Close voted: Plain css & Js Q.

Comment: Yes this is true, although I am using a plugin that filters the wp_list_pages, as well as a Custom Walker, so this gets pretty deep into WordPress fast. I thought by including the screenshots of the CSS elements, that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery like this:

```
jQuery('ul.children li:last').addClass('last');
```

And then CSS it with:

```
ul.children li.last {
    color: red;
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for my previous answer, thought you wanted to style the last two elements :) if you have nested lists then use the `ul.children:last li:last` selector for jQuery.

Comment: This is great. Except my goal is to style the last item of each first level list. See here: http://screencast.com/t/MBtFzK7ZYe. I'm not quite sure how the above selector works but maybe you had a simple answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AlxVallejo that's quite tricky. Perhaps something like `ul.children li:last, ul.children ul:last li:last` will work. In your screenshot you have different levels, not sure about the class names but it would be much easier if you pasted your entier HTML code and let us know which items you'd like to be "last" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you post your HTML that would be help in figuring out what the CSS needs to be. Also, please indicate in the HTML which "last items" you want highlight. Since you have nested lists there will be many tags taht "li:last-child" applies to.